# Replacing part of a class with jscript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the scale from deg C to deg F for data being read from sensors

Sensor-1:  ℃

For this my jscript function is as follows

```
function changeScale(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dataS00");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML = x[i].innerHTML.replace("&#8457;", "&#8451;");
    }
}
```

However the deg C still shows up on the HTML page instead of deg F when I set a checkbox

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Simple answer, don't change styles with javascript. Create 2 classes and assign the correct class to the items to display the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using javascript, you can change the `innerHTML` simply.

```
function changeScale(){
   // Change will be here
   document.getElementsByClassName("dataS00")[0].innerHTML = "&#8451;";
}
```

Comment: Doing so replaces the HTML line with just the symbol for deg F. So instead of the page showing up as "Sensor-1: XX deg F" it shows up as "deg F"